# Table View custom cells with different data

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, tableview, uitableview

So, I want to put different images into tableview cells and I have 3 different files. I already did some coding but now I have problem finishing it up. Please, look at my code and tell how to handle this strugle, Im new to this. (Stuck for a whole day) ... The whole point of this is to have **custom cells with an different images and two labels.**

> First file

```
class MenuCells {

private var _cellTitle: String
private var _cellDetails: String
private var _cellIcon: Array<String>

var cellTitle: String {
    return _cellTitle
}

var cellDetails: String {
    return _cellDetails
}

var cellIcon: Array<String> {
    return _cellIcon
}

init(cellTitle: String, cellDetails: String, cellIcon: Array<String>) {

    _cellTitle = cellTitle
    _cellDetails = cellDetails
    _cellIcon = cellIcon

}

func cellData() {
    _cellTitle = "x"
    _cellDetails = "y"
    _cellIcon = ["1","2","3","4"]
}

}
```

> Second File

```
class MenuCell: UITableViewCell {


@IBOutlet weak var bg: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var cellTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cellDetails: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cellIcon: UIImageView!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()


}

func configureCell(menuCell: MenuCells) {

    cellTitle.text = menuCell.cellTitle
    cellDetails.text = menuCell.cellDetails
    cellIcon.image = UIImage(named: "\(menuCell.cellIcon)")

}
}
```

> Third File (Here Im stuck, I dont know how implement the data)

```
import UIKit

class MenuVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var tableMenu: UITableView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableMenu.delegate = self
    tableMenu.delegate = self



}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "menuCell", for: indexPath) as? MenuCell


    return cell
}


}
```

Comment: Your code is perfect. almost

Comment: The viewDidLoad sets `tableMenu.delegate = self` twice, and by the looks of it, you haven't set your dataSource. Try setting your dataSource by either replacing one of those lines with `tableMenu.dataSource = self`, or by connecting it on your storyboard to your ViewController via the connections inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "menuCell", for: indexPath) as? MenuCell

// create object of MenuCells file and assign your variables.Instead of creating array of images in MenuCell, create array in this file and send image as a param 1-by-1.
let myMenuCells = MenuCells(cellTitle: "Title", cellDetails: "Details", cellIcon: image) 

//By this below method set your data in your outlets. As this func is already doing so call it.
cell.configureCell(menuCell: myMenuCells)

return cell
    }
```

and change

- `private var _cellIcon: Array<String>` to `private var _cellIcon: String` because you just send image name and `func configureCell` auto assign image to your outlet.
- `cellIcon.image = UIImage(named: "\(menuCell.cellIcon)")` to `cellIcon.image = UIImage(named: menuCell.cellIcon)`

Answer (score 0):

If you have prototype cells in your storyboard, you could set an identifier to each of your prototype cells, and use if statements to have the code run separately for each cell. (So check if the identifier is for cell A, if it is, run the setup for cell A, else run the setup for cell B).

Comment: Thanks for advice, I was thinking about it since I need only 4 cells now but later on I will need much more. Currently none of the cells is showing up do you have any ideas why ?

Comment: At a guess, your viewDidLoad. You have set tableMenu.delegate = self, twice. You need to have your dataSource set.

Comment: No problem, that's the only thing that jumps out to me in the code to be wrong, but it's an easy mistake to make.